# [Unity 3D]I want access Android Camera and pick up path

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, plugins

I make an AARplugins for android which accesses Camera.
But it does not activate `onActivityResult`.

```
public static void showCamera ( )     // Connect Camera
{
    String Uri;

    Activity CameraActivity = UnityPlayer.currentActivity;

    Toast.makeText(CameraActivity ,   "first"  ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(" before ImageUrl@@@@@@ ", "first");


CameraActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
{
    public void run() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        CameraActivity.startActivityForResult(intent,1);
    }
});
}
```

///////////////Don't activate↓//////////////////////////////////

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)                           
{
    Log.d(" before ImageUrl@@@@@@ ", "twotwotwotwotwotwotwo"); //Don't activate
}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

why don't activate this?

Comment: access Camera sucess. but dose't active 'onActivityResult()' funtion

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

Camera permission

```
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 112;


    btn_cam.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                        String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA};
                        if (!hasPermissions(mContext, PERMISSIONS)) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CAMERAE );
                        } else {

                            //open camera
                        }
                    } else {

                        //open camera
                    }

                }
            });
        }
```

get Permissions Result

```
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CAMERA: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                   //open camera
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```

check permissions  for marshmallow

```
    private static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Comment: I access Camera sucess. but dose't active 'onActivityResult()' funtion.

Comment: Where you call startActivityForResult in activity or in fragment?